# PHP append json with $ to http request body

Tags: php, json, string, request

```
$body->append('{"stage_id": "43"}');
```

I would like to make the "43" dynamic and use a $variable for the value: How should look the Syntax look like?

Comment: Like any other php variable, you even wrote the syntax in your question `$variable`

Comment: Before you go much further, it might be better to actually use the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function and native arrays, rather than building your own JSON piecemeal like this. For example: `json_encode([ 'stage_id' => 43 ])`.

Comment: Don't generate JSON by hand. Use the PHP function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just like this:

```
<?php
    $var = 43;
    $array = array('stage_id'=>$var);
    $json = json_encode($array);
    $body->append($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This will help you

$body->append('{"stage_id": $variable}');

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare a variable and assign your dynamic value in it as per your requirement.

```
$variable = Value;   // if value is number like 0,1,2,3,4 or anything.
$variable = "value"; // if value is string put it inside ' or " quotes.
```

Now you can use your value as a variable:

```
body->append("{'stage_id': '$variable'}");
```